# What is the Strong Parameter for updating nested record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend

I'm a junior backend developer starting with Rails 7.0.

Looking at the documentation of Rails here:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-fields-for-helper-index-option

point 8.3 , it is stated that we can use :index option to output the form.
This is the example taken from the doc

```
{
  "person" => {
    "name" => "Bob",
    "address" => {
      "23" => {
        "city" => "Paris"
      },
      "45" => {
        "city" => "London"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to output the form correctly in views,
but unable to create the **correct strong parameters** for that structure.

this is my current strong parameter:

```
    params.require(:person)
          .permit(:name, address: [:id, :city])
```

this produce error unknown attribute address, so I'm unable to put the record on database

The doc doesn't give any explanation on how to do strong parameter on nested attribute with index.

Thank you

Comment: How is your Person model defined?

Comment: You're working with rails 7, but tagged the question with rails 4/5....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model should have

```rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

for nested attributes to work. Or, the attribute address is misspelled in your model.

Comment: this is working for point 10. in documentation: "10 Building Complex Forms". but for point 8.3 it's not working

Comment: I ended using this solution. I think the documentation for point 8.3 is broken